# scrollIntoView в элемент аккордеона

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Я делаю словарь русского языка в виде аккордеона, где каждое слово в своей ячейке.

Сейчас мне надо, чтобы ящик содержания каждой ячейки автоматически расположился в центре экрана при щелчке на ячейку выбранного слова.

[image: словарь]

Если щёлкну ячейку "число", например, так произойдёт:

[image: результат, который хочу исправить.]

Надо прокручивать вручную до желаемого содержания:

[image: Желаемый экран]

Что делать? Я читал о команде scrollIntoView, но не знаю, как её приложить к моему аккордеону. Вот отрывки моего кода:

CSS:

```
 .accordionWrapper { (...) }
.accordionItem { (...) }
.accordionItemHeading {
cursor: pointer; (...) 
}
.close .accordionItemContent {
                height:0px;
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
                float:left;
                display:block;
            }
.open .accordionItemContent {
                (...)
                display:block;
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
                -webkit-transform-origin: top;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
 .open .accordionItemHeading {
                margin:0px;
                -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
                -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
                -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
                -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
                (...)
            }
(...)
```

HTML/PHP:

```
<div class="accordionWrapper">
<div class='accordionItem close'>

<h2 class='accordionItemHeading'> <!--PHP здесь--> </h2>

<div class='accordionItemContent'>
<!--PHP здесь -->
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>   
var accItem = document.getElementsByClassName('accordionItem');
var accHD = document.getElementsByClassName('accordionItemHeading');
var accCon = document.getElementsByClassName('accordionItemContent');

for (i = 0; i < accHD.length; i++) {
accHD[i].addEventListener('click', toggleItem, false);
      }
function toggleItem() {
     var itemClass = this.parentNode.className;
     for (i = 0; i < accItem.length; i++) {
               accItem[i].className = 'accordionItem close';
                    }
      if (itemClass == 'accordionItem close') {
               this.parentNode.className = 'accordionItem open';

               accCon.scrollIntoView();
                    }

                }


</script>
```

Весь код работает, кроме строки accCon.scrollIntoView();. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Попробуйте `accItem[i].scrollIntoView()`

Comment: Попробовал, но не работало. Надо ввести ту строку внутри функции if, заменив accCon?

Comment: Да, вместо `accCon.scrollIntoView()`.